# Why does React Delete method is not working and giving me Status 404?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net

I'm learning react. I'm trying to create a simple CRUD App, everything is working fine except for its delete method.

It gives me

`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

`DELETE https://localhost:7211/delete-post-by-id/12 404 (Not Found)`

But the item I'm trying to delete is existent. Below is my data from DB.

```
{postId: 6, name: 'Post 6', email: 'database6@email.com', contact: '000-0006'}
{postId: 8, name: 'dev', email: 'dev@email.com', contact: '5080756'}
{postId: 9, name: 'Test Name', email: 'test@email.com', contact: '88801-222'}
{postId: 10, name: 'ABCD EDFG', email: 'abced@email.com', contact: '1235-22'}
{postId: 11, name: 'esfdsdf', email: '12@email.com', contact: '123512-12'}
{postId: 12, name: 'asdasd', email: 'asd@email.com', contact: '124234'}
```

Below is my code to delete with a button

```
I mapped it as user here
<button onClick={()=>{if(window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete user: "${user.name}"?`)) deleteUser(user.postId)}} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm ">Delete</button>
```

Here's the rest of my delete query/code.

```
function deleteUser(postId){
  const url  = `${Constants.API_URL_DELETE_POST_BY_ID}/${postId}`
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseFromServer =>{
    console.log(responseFromServer);
    onUserDeleted(postId);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    alert(error);
  })
}
```

In this, I tried to check it against its index so it doesn't have to make another API Call once deleted.

```
 function onUserDeleted(deletedUserPostId){
      let usersCopy = [...users];
      const index = usersCopy.findIndex((usersCopyUser, currentIndex) => {
        if(usersCopyUser.postId === deletedUserPostId){
          return true;

        }
      });
      if(index !== -1){
        usersCopy.splice(index, 1);
      }
      setUsers(usersCopy);
      alert('User successfully deleted')
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help, I'm running of out options. Please also note that DELETE method is perfectly working from my backend. Thanks a lot.

I tried  mostly everything, target another key, delete from DB et al. But still nothing. Please help

Comment: `DELETE method is perfectly working from my backend` so why is your backend returning a 404 status with invalid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!

to answer my own Q, apparently, in my server. I have written the query as
 `app.MapDelete("/delete-post-by-id/", async (int postId) => {.../rest of the code}`

instead of

`app.MapDelete("/delete-post-by-id/**{postId}**", async (int postId) => {.../rest of the code}`